# Cheese is not working with Ubuntu 11.10 in HPG62 laptop

Tags: cheese

When I run cheese in terminal, it gives following message and cheese comes up with black screen, and nothing works in it.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

```
(cheese:2966): Gtk-WARNING **: Attempting to add a widget with type GtkImage to a GtkButton, but as a GtkBin subclass a GtkButton can only contain one widget at a time; it already contains a widget of type GtkLabel

** (cheese:2966): WARNING **: Could not get buffers from device '/dev/video0'.

** (cheese:2966): WARNING **: Could not map buffers from device '/dev/video0'

** (cheese:2966): WARNING **: Could not negotiate format
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved: I just updated my Ubuntu 11.10 and then installed [guvcview [image: Install guvcview]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/guvcview).

Now everything is working fine. Both guvcview and cheese are working.